# PHP mangles beginning of verification link parameters

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been battling with this for more than 24 hours inclusive now.  I have setup my server to setup user accounts and sending them verification links via e-mail. Everything works well but I am having trouble with two string variables hash and token with values derived from a mySql database.  Each time an e-mail generated these variables parse their data with the first three characters mangled up:

```
http://verify.myserver.com/objects/1.8.12.7.10.1.9/verify-email.php?mm_function=submit&hashü41faa912dd9451a8d397fc9386ca1c69&mm_tokenü2rnjrcbhn3qegtu46np03p5pg6aczbtrs51782fkuwq2c8w9m80enutwruydwewca&mm_timezone=2&mm_charset=utf-8
```

The link should be:

```
http://verify.myserver.com/objects/1.8.12.7.10.1.9/verify-email.php?mm_function=submit&hash=fc41faa912dd9451a8d397fc9386ca1c69&mm_token=fc22rnjrcbhn3qegtu46np03p5pg6aczbtrs51782fkuwq2c8w9m80enutwruydwewca&mm_timezone=2&mm_charset=utf-8
```

I have tried mixing and matching the code to no avail. Currently, my code is as follows:

```
$weblink = "http://verify.myserver.com/objects/1.8.12.7.10.1.9/verify-email.php?";
$weblink . "mm_function=submit&hash=" . $hash . "&mm_token=" . $token . "&mm_timezone=" . $timezone . "&mm_charset=utf-8";
```

What's odd is that if I just place the $hash and $token as part of the email, independent of the link, they all come out fine.

I am using mySql running the InnoDB Engine, DB Collation is latin7_general_ci.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is, that your problem comes from different encodings in the database (latin) and in your email (utf-8).

Comment: I have always used latin7_general_ci before with no problems at all. This is the first time I am doing an application that sends out verification links.  But why is it that the variables send out the correct strings if not associated with the $weblink string? I will try other collations or even another DB engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the e-mail encoding was the culprit.  Thanks to oktopus, I fixed it in the headers using charset=iso-8859-1 like so:

```
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$headers = "From: Some Sender <someone@example.com>". PHP_EOL;
$headers.= "Return-Path: Some Sender <someone@example.com>". PHP_EOL;
$headers.= "Organization: My Organization>". PHP_EOL; 
$headers.= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1". PHP_EOL;
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0". PHP_EOL;
$headers.= "X-Priority: 3". PHP_EOL;

$weblink = "http://verify.myserver.com/objects/1.8.12.7.10.1.9/process.php?mm_function=submit&";
$weblink.= "mm_hash=$hash&mm_token=$verification&mm_timezone=$timezone&mm_charset=iso-8859-1";

mail($recipient, "Account Verification Link", "Hello $recipient,". PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ."Please follow the link below to verify and activate your account:". PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $weblink . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "Thank you.". PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "App Support Team", $headers);
```

Comment: I would have suggested to use `http_build_query()` to construct the query-string as well.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  Being a newbie that I am, it's always nice to learn new things from the community.